# Google Drive API shows consent screen on server browser

Tags: java, oauth-2.0, google-drive-api, google-oauth, google-api-java-client

So here is the code that I am using for connecting to Google Drive API and authenticate my users, the problem I am facing is that whenever I call the function to authenticate the user the consent screen is being displayed on the server (where tomcat is installed, not the PC where the user is working on). I know it is a strange issue and I cannot find anything on this in the forums.

```
private Credential getCredentials(final NetHttpTransport HTTP_TRANSPORT) throws IOException {

    final String CREDENTIALS_FILE_PATH = "/credentials.json";
    final String TOKENS_DIRECTORY_PATH = "/tokens";
    final List<String> SCOPES = Collections.singletonList(DriveScopes.DRIVE);

    InputStream in = this.getClass().getResourceAsStream(CREDENTIALS_FILE_PATH);
    if (in == null) {
        throw new FileNotFoundException("Resource not found: " + CREDENTIALS_FILE_PATH);
    }
    GoogleClientSecrets clientSecrets = GoogleClientSecrets.load(JSON_FACTORY, new InputStreamReader(in));

    // Build flow and trigger user authorization request.
    GoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow flow = new GoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow.Builder(
            HTTP_TRANSPORT, JSON_FACTORY, clientSecrets, SCOPES)
            .setDataStoreFactory(new FileDataStoreFactory(new java.io.File(TOKENS_DIRECTORY_PATH)))
            .setAccessType("offline")
            .build();

    LocalServerReceiver receiver = new LocalServerReceiver.Builder().setPort(9999).build();
    return new AuthorizationCodeInstalledApp(flow, receiver).authorize("user");
}
```

After I call this method, the application is opening the default browser of the server (Chrome) and showing the consent screen. I don't know what I am doing wrong here. Thanks for helping. Cheers!

Answer (score 2):

`GoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow.Builder` is designed to be used by installed applications.

what you should be using is  `GoogleBrowserClientRequestUrl`

```
public void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)throws IOException {
  String url = new GoogleBrowserClientRequestUrl("812741506391.apps.googleusercontent.com",
      "https://oauth2.example.com/oauthcallback", Arrays.asList(
          "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email",
          "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.profile")).setState("/profile").build();
  response.sendRedirect(url);
}
```

[#client-side_applications](https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/java/google-api-java-client/oauth2#client-side_applications)